# First Client with JAX-WS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I try to write the first application for this article http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html#bnayr.

BUT I can not understand where this class and its methods.

> import helloservice.endpoint.HelloService;

Answer (score 0):

`HelloService` is something generated from the `wsgen` tool, a so-called *portable artifact*. It gets generated by the build process.

But if you are trying to learn about java web services, then you might want to take the [recent Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxws.htm#BNAYL) instead of the old version 5.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the HelloWorld Webservice Tutorial below .It contains detail steps with proper explanation as well as code.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-devaxis2part2/section3.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-devws-jsme/section3.html

Hope this helps you!